# Django form customise FileField

Tags: python, django

I'm doing a super simple image upload for my django application and I'm stuck on customising the label that permit the upload.

Right now, it looks like:

[image]

Which is pretty ugly and has nothing to do with what I did in my code.

I would like to customise the button style and have the text "no file chosen" on the top of it (or under, whatever).

The code:

```
class ImageForm(forms.Form):
    imageFile = forms.FileField(
        label = _('select an image')
    )
```

and my model:

```
class ImageVisionModel(CMSPlugin):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Computer vision demo'
```

Because I'm not storing the image.

So I don't know if I'm missing something, but when I inspect the element, label + text are only one and single element.
And except the text on the right of the label, it seems that I can't modify anything on the button directly with the css.

I looked on StackOverflow and the django doc but I found nothing.

Or maybe am I missing something?

Comment: Style of file-input defined by a browser and can't be customised. You can hide input and show instead styled DIVs or text-inputs. But it's about html\css, not django.

Comment: So, basically, if I create my own button and hide the file-input, I have to simulate the input click with JS?

Comment: Maybe this can help https://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/mxq9R/

Comment: Oh yeah, ok, many thanks Sergey!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did with the help of link shared by @Sergey

```
<div class="upload">
   {{ myForm.picture}}
</div>
```

In css file

```
.upload {
    width: 157px;
    height: 57px;
    background: url(https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-dqTIJRTqEAQ/UJaofTQm3hI/AAAAAAAABHo/w7ruR1SOIsA/s157/upload.png);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.upload input {
    display: block !important;
    width: 157px !important;
    height: 57px !important;
    opacity: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```